# ERROR: (gcloud.run.services.update) PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission 'run.services.get' denied on resource 'namespaces/*/services/test-repo'

Tags: google-cloud-run

I have following permissions in google cloud.

1. BigQuery Admin
2. Cloud Functions Admin
3. Cloud Scheduler Admin
4. Compute Admin
5. Editor
6. Source Repository Administrator
7. Storage Admin

I am creating a cloud run container using cloud repository. But getting following error.

> ERROR: build step 2 "gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:slim"
> failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1 ERROR Finished Step #2 -
> "Deploy" Step #2 - "Deploy": ERROR: (gcloud.run.services.update)
> PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission 'run.services.get' denied on resource
> 'namespaces/buypower-mobile-app/services/test-repo' (or resource may
> not exist).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you're using Cloud Build to deploy the Cloud Run service, then the error you’re getting is because the Service Account used by Cloud Build does not have sufficient permissions to update the Cloud Run service, according to [the official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/deploying#permissions_required_to_deploy).

The specific error is that permission is denied on `run.services.get`. This method is part of either `roles/run.admin` or `roles/run.developer`. Both roles include the permission `run.services.update`, which it'll need.

To get it working, you will need to add that one of those roles to the Service Account that is being used by Cloud Build.

Comment: Amazing explaination Daz! I got onto it now. Pity that "CloudRun Viewer" and "CloudRun Runner" are not enough for this. So weird.

Answer (score 6):

[image]In gcp console Go to Cloud Build -> settings and enable Cloud Run and Service Accounts.

Comment: This is the answer if you are doing your first deployment and you already gave proper permissions to the Cloud Build default service account.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify that the default Service Account used by the Cloud Build service is:

```
<project-number>@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com
```

And in order for it to deploy a Cloud Run service it needs the following roles:

```
Cloud Build Service Account
Cloud Run Admin
```

If the Cloud Run service being deployed has a Service Account, then you need to add `Service Account User` role as well.

If the Cloud Run service being deployed has a customer managed Encryption Key from KMS, then you need to add `Cloud KMS CryptoKey Encrypter/Decrypter` role as well.

Comment: I think its <project-number>@..

Answer (score 0):

Along with @DazWilkin's answer I was having difficulty determining whether the service account actually had the `run.services.update` permission. Especially since I was using Github Actions with Workload Identity Pools for auth and impersonating a service account.

I'd recommend doing the following:

1. Check if your auth is working correctly

```yaml
   - id: 'auth'
      name: 'Authenticate to Google Cloud'
      uses: 'google-github-actions/auth@v0'
      with:
        workload_identity_provider: 'projects/xxxxx/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/my_pool/providers/my_provider'
        service_account: 'my-service-account@{PROJECT_ID}.iam.gserviceaccount.com'
        # this will make this step fail if auth fails
        token_format: 'access_token'
```

2. Check if the service account used above and in the `google-github-actions/deploy-cloudrun@v0` has the `run.services.update` permission. There are 2 places you can check.

   a) [Policy Troubleshooter](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/troubleshooter) - Use the service account, select your project, and enter the permission. This will immediately tell you whether you have the permission or not

   b) [Policy Analyzer](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/analyzer) - Create Custom query, use Permission as parameter, click continue and Run Query. This will show you all the principals that have the permission you're looking for
3. If your service account doesn't have the correct permission you need to add it from the [IAM & Admin -> IAM page](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam)